# What should the length of my wire be in order to get a surface area of 10cm^2?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, geometry, estimation

I would like to make a flat coil out of a steel wire that is $1.22 ~\text{mm}$ in thickness (or $1.22~\text{mm}$ in diameter). I wish to make the coil up the[image] wire into a flat disk that has a surface area of $10 ~\text{cm^2}$. What should the length of my wire be?

I tried calculating this out a while back and I had gotten around $28.4 cm$ of wire, but after running an electrolysis reaction with the coil, I realized that my current density wasn't adding up with the supposed area I was making my coils. (Any calculations in order to get the answer would be appreciated)

Comment: You calculated the surface area of the wire itself regardless of its shape. I think that when you roll the wire into a flat spiral, its effective surface area is reduced and is now much closer to the area of a double-sided flat disk (about 6.5 cm^2 in your case).

Comment: do you want a disc whose size is a circle of area 10 sq cm or do you want a mass of wire with true surface area of 10 sq cm which happens to look like a disc (and will in fact form a circle of area much less than 10 sq cm)? that will influence the answer

Comment: I want to make a disc that has a surface area of 10 sq cm. Mass is not really a concern for me in this experiment

Comment: When viewed from the side, 820 mm of 1.22 mm diameter wire, will appear as an area of 1000 mm^2 = 10 cm^2. And it doesn't matter all too much how you coil this up, as long as no part of the wire gets hidden, the area stays the same.

Comment: The above assumes you want to obtain a coil that has area 1000 mm^2 when viewed from above. (See @gregsan 's remark)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends how tight your coiling is.

If the wire doesn't touch itself, i.e. without any contact surface excluded with itself, then the area of the wire exposed is simply the area of the wire :

$$
A = 2\pi rL
$$
which gives immediately the length of wire you wish (with $d$ the diameter of your wire) :

$$
L = \frac{A}{d\pi}
$$
$$
L = \frac{10^{-3}}{1.22\pi.10^{-3}} \simeq 26.09\text{ cm}
$$

On the other hand, if your wire touches itself then the area exposed is reduced, and if you take the extreme where your wire is of square section and each loop touching perfectly, then the area is :

$$
 A = 2dL + 2\pi Rd
$$
Which is the total surface of a coin of radius $R$ and thickness $d$.

As the volume is conserved, we have obviously 
$$
 V = \pi R^2d = d^2L \\
 L = \frac{\pi R^2}{d}
$$
Solving the second order equation for R, we finally get :
$$
 R = -\frac{d}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d^2+2A/\pi}\simeq 1.2 \text{cm}\\
 L = 37.20 \text{cm}
$$
You seem closer to the first case though, but a little math exercise never is bad!

Answer (score 0):

The key idea here is that the volume of the wire before and after flattening it should be almost exactly the same, since you aren't removing or adding any metal, just smushing it around.

If $L$ is the length of the wire, $r_{wire}$ is the radius of the wire, $t$ is the thickness of the disk, and $A$ is the desired area of the disk,

$$V_{wire} = L ( \pi r_{wire}^2 )$$

$$V_{disk} = t A$$
Set the volumes equal to each other:
$$V_{wire} = V_{disk}$$
$$L ( \pi r_{wire}^2 ) = t A$$
$$L = \frac{t A}{ \pi r_{wire}^2 }$$
$$L = t \frac{A}{ \pi r_{wire}^2} $$

Notice that the required length $L$ depends on both the radius of the wire (which you have specified) **and** the final thickness of the disk; if you want a super-thin disc, you don't need as much wire.  If you want a thick disk, you'll need more wire.

So, you will need to decide how thin you want your final disk to be before you can calculate this.

Comment: Hey Brionius, thanks a lot for the input. After taking your comments about the disc thickness into account, I realized I wanted something as thick as the wire (1.22mm). That being said, I tried doing out the calculations for the length of the wire and I was getting a length of wire that seemed too small (something around 2.69 cm). When I did the calculations out, I went on the basis that my radius was 1.202 cm by solving for it using the surface area of a cylinder equation(A=2πrh+2πr^2).